# Finding weather data to use for training a neural network

Tags: neural-network, forecasting, training-data

I'm looking for some downloadable weather data I can use to train a neural network to do forecasting, where can I find some? Basically things like temperature, humidity, wind speed/direction, anything and everything that might help a neural network do simple forecasting.

Comment: Any particular reason why this should be closed?

Comment: wunderground.com has a fairly large amount of hourly historical data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the NOAA datasets:

http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/

http://www.nws.noaa.gov/gis/

http://sos.noaa.gov/datasets/

Comment: the first link is exactly what i want except they charge...

Comment: Your local university may have a deal allowing you to access a bunch of data free of charge. Authentication doesn't seem to be particularly fancy.

Comment: The National Climatic Data Center's [Climate Data Online](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/) offers access to free data.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how reliable you need the data to be.

NOAA direct is ok, however they often have missing data segments.

We've always used commercial quality services like Weathernation or FeedSyndicate or weatherbug.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google came up with this:

1. [Weather Base](http://www.weatherbase.com/)
2. [California Weather Database](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/WEATHER/wxretrieve.html)
3. [AWIS Climate Data](http://www.awis.com/Climate_Data/AWIS_Climate_Data.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/gis/) the type of information you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The EneryPlus website has a bunch of data you can download from [here](http://apps1.eere.energy.gov/buildings/energyplus/cfm/weather_data3.cfm/region=2_asia_wmo_region_2/country=IND/cname=India#instructions)